# Makefile variables using include directive and targe specific variable

Tags: variables, makefile, include, target

Here is a very simple test and I cannot understand where I am wrong:

File Makefile.inc

```
MSG = I am

myprog: USE_FOO = 1

ifeq ($(USE_FOO), 1)
  MSG += using foo
else
  MSG += not using foo
endif
```

File Makefile

```
include Makefile.inc

all: myprog

myprog:
    @echo "USE_FOO = $(USE_FOO)"
    @echo $(MSG)
```

And I obtain:

```
$> make
USE_FOO = 1
I am not using foo
```

Could you tell me please, why my message is not "I am using foo" ?

Comment: Why have you specified a target name in the include Makefile?

Comment: Because I only want to use foo only for that target. In my real program, I have several targets and only two of them needs to use foo. I just want to set the variable USE_FOO to 1 in order to make simpler my Makefiles. According the answer below, it seems that the only way to have some target specific variables is to use the following syntax:
_target_: _assignment_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ifeq` is not evaluated in the context of the target `myprog`, so it is evaluated to false and the MSG is set to "I am not using foo."

You could instead use `File Makefile.inc`:

```
MSG = I am not using foo

myprog: USE_FOO = 1
myprog: MSG=I am using foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. USE_FOO variable becomes useless. I will assign all target specific variables using the syntax: _target_: _assignment_